# processing large files in parallel using java

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, forkjoinpool, parallelstream

I am attempting to process ten files, with some being smaller and others containing up to three million records. I have grouped the files into five groups based on logical dependencies, with variable file counts in each group. Group 1 has one file, group 2 has two files, group 3 has four files, group 4 has two files, and group 5 has one file. These files within each group can be run independently of each other.

I am using JDK 11 and tried using `parallelstream()` for each group, but it seems that the files are not being processed in parallel. Instead, they are being processed one after the other.

```
// files added to respective file group
FileGroup group1 = new FileGroup();
group1.add(file1);
group1.add(file2);
group1.add(file3);

.. and so on for each group

// groups added to following 'groups' collection
List<FileGroup> groups = new ArrayList(); 
groups.add(group1);
.
.
.
groups.add(group5);

// use parallel stream over groups of files. 
groups.parallelStream().forEach(group -> {...} )
```

if a group has four files, four parallel threads would be spawn. each thread will get one file which may have 3 million records to process.

What is the best way to execute this model?

Comment: How did you determine that they are processed one after another?